# Replacing Text with an image with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm looking to replace text in a table with an image. I will have three variations of text:
Strong, Medium, Weak. This is to prioritise the strength of the coffee products. If the text says strong, then I want to replace with 'strong.png' etc. I've got this far but now stuck for ideas. The below doesn't work.

My code so far:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.data-table tr .data').each(function () {
        string = $(this).text('Strong');
        $(this).html('<img src="strong.png" alt="' + string + '" />');
    });
});

</script>
```

The table markup is:

```
 <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <colgroup><col width="25%">
    <col>
    </colgroup><tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <th class="label">Coffee Strength</th>
            <td class="data last">Strong</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't worked as it should. There will be other attributes within the table that I DON'T want image replacements for those - just for the Coffee Strength. So this has to work on just the words 'strong, medium or Weak.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.data-table tr .data').each(function () {
        var string = $.trim($(this).text());
        $(this).html('<img src="' + string + '.png" alt="' + string + '" />');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A3Zgt/)

Comment: Absolutely perfect. You're a star. Very impressed by the way you have done this. THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, this hasn't worked as it should. There will be other attributes within the table that I DON'T want image replacements for those - just for the Coffee Strength. So this has to work on just the words 'strong, medium or Weak.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.data-table tr .data').html(function() {
    var currentText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    return '<img src="' + currentText + '.png" alt="' + currentText + '" />';
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jRELP/**